# Add shortcode inside the_content() after 25% of content

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add a block to all my posts, i am using the_content Hook to add the shortcode, the code below adds the shortcode in the end of the content, is there something i can do to put the shortcode for example after 25% of the content?

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_shortchode_in_single_page' );
function my_shortchode_in_single_page($content){
    if(is_single())
        return $content . do_shortcode('SHORTCODE HERE');
    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually we can't found 25% of content but we can put it after a certain number of p tag. you can 0 to which number of p tag in content.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'ak_the_content_filter', 10, 1);
function ak_the_content_filter($content)
{
    $parags = explode('</p>', $content);
    $parags[0] .= '<br>'.do_shortcode('[SHORTCODE HERE]');// add whatever you want after first paragraph

    $content_new = '';

    foreach ($parags as $parag) {
        $content_new .= $parag;
    }

    return $content_new;
}
```

Comment: ;) Tks, what if i wanted to add it above that element?